# Android widget question

Tags: android, widget

My question is: how can I determine if my widget is already placed on the home screen? For example: I added the widget for the first time, and when I try to add it again, in onUpdate() method, I want to execute come code. Something like

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

if(widget_already_exists){

 //do something

   }
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.   Alex Ady*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your app widget IDs. When you see a new one in `onUpdate()` and you already had one, then the user is adding a second instance. Don't forget to remove them from your log in `onDeleted()` of your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Comment: Yes, now I am using SharedPreferences, but I wanted to know if there is another way, if the system keeps track of the widgets added by a certain provider.

Comment: @Alex Ady: You can also query the `AppWidgetManager` for your app widget IDs. You do not get informed by a separate callback method, though, beyond `onUpdate()` for any new app widgets.